# Next.js generating a sitemap without a server

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a blog created in Next.js. I'm hosting it after exporting all the pages to static HTML files. The first sitemap that I added to the site was one that used getServerSideProps() and returned XML. The sitemap is generated from the Firebase DB. I would like to export the sitemap as a static every time I build the project. Here is what I have going so far, this is just rendering the sitemap inside a React component.

sitemap.xml.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

import { parseString } from "xml2js";

import { baseURL } from "../lib/constants";

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const { db } = await import("../lib/firebase");
  const result = await db.collection("root").doc("sitemap").get();

  const urls = result.data().urls;

  const pages = [];

  //loc, lastmod, changefreq, priority
  //NO FIRST AND LAST BRACKETS
  //loc;lastmod;changefreq;priority
  urls.forEach((dataString) => {
    const data = dataString.split(";");
    pages.push({
      loc: data[0],
      lastmod: data[1],
      changefreq: data[2],
      priority: data[3],
    });
  });

  return {
    props: {
      pages,
    },
    revalidate: 86400,
  };
};

export default function Sitemap({ pages }) {
  const sitemap = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    &lt;urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"&gt;
    <br/>
    <br/>
      ${pages
        .map((page) => {
          return `
            &lt;url&gt;
            <br/>
            &emsp;&lt;loc&gt;${baseURL}/${page.loc}&lt;/loc&gt;
              <br/>
              &emsp;&lt;lastmod&gt;${page.lastmod}&lt;/lastmod&gt;
              <br/>
              &emsp;&lt;changefreq&gt;${page.changefreq}&lt;/changefreq&gt;
              <br/>
              &emsp;&lt;priority&gt;${page.priority}&lt;/priority&gt;
              <br/>
            &lt;/url&gt;
            <br/>
            
          `;
        })
        .join("")}
        <br/>
    &lt;/urlset&gt;
  `;

  const [parsedXML, setParsedXML] = useState(null);

  parseString(sitemap, (error, result) => {
    console.dir(result);
    //setParsedXML(result);
  });

  return (
    <div
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: sitemap,
      }}
    >
    </div>
  );
}
```

I would like to have this sitemap as a proper XML file.
Please advise.

P.S.: Does it make a difference, having the sitemap as an XML file or just displaying all the URLs in a React component?

Thank you :):):)

Comment: I use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-sitemap and run the `next-sitemap` ina `postbuild` script of `package.json` so it's always up to date on build. I think your code needs very slight modification to achieve your goal: move the code that compute the sitemap to an independant `.js` file ; import this file in your page (in order to correctly refactor your code) ; and create a script that also import this file but instead uses `fs` to create a new `XML` file.